# Objective-C memory issue with performSelector and infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, infinite-loop, performselector

I'm working on a project in which I have to try executing a given method for a given time (see it like an automatic mode) and if the auto mode doesn't succeed, I switch to manual mode. Just to warn you, I'm quite new to Objective-C and iOS dev, so the error might be obvious.

So far, here is what I've done :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {  
    [self performSelector:@selector(autoMode) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];  
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(switchManualMode) withObject:nil];  
}


-(void)autoMode {  
    @autoreleasepool {  
        while (isAutoMode == true) {  
            if ([session isRunning])  
                [self captureImage];  
                // NSLog(@"test");
       }  
    }  
}  

-(void)switchManualMode {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
    isAutoMode = false;
    self.button.enabled = true;

    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Changement de mode"
                                                    message:@"Du a un délai trop long, la capture automatique va être desactivée. La capture se fait maintenant de manière manuelle Touchez l'écran pour prendre une photo."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

I have a couple issues here:
- The first one is that the memory used peak and the app crashes.
- The second one is that switchManualMode is never called.

I've tried to just print "test" in the logs (instead of actually call the function "captureImage"), and when I do that, everything is fine.

I can't post the code of captureImage, but the method tries to get an image from a AVCaptureSession, and then does somme processing on it.
Anyway, I don't understand why switchManualMode is called in a case and not in the other.

Comment: a few notes: why `@autoreleasepool`? you have to specify that `[alert show]`should be execute don the main thread - currently you are operating on a background thread. Capturing images over and over again will just cause an extremely high cpu and memory usage.

Comment: I added an @autoreleasepool because that's what I found when looking for a solution to release memory with infinite loops. And the [alert show] works perfectly when I replace captureImage with the NSLog in comment.

Comment: it will not work perfectly, it is not determined at what point in time the alert view will actually be shown. if it works for you right now: great. it will not continue to.

Comment: Ok I will try and find a way to "force" it to be executed on the main thread.

Comment: how did you define `isAutoMode` var?

Comment: isAutoMode is declared as True (so that the auto mode is the first one to give it a try), and if it doesn't work after, say 10 seconds, switchManualMode sets it to false. That way, the infinite loop stops, and the autoMode method ends. At least, that's what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you put the @autoreleasepool at exactly the wrong place. It should be *inside* the loop. You are running an infinite loop within *the same* autorelease pool; that's asking for out of memory problems. Capturing images at the highest possible rate doesn't exactly help.

The other problem is that performSelector will run on the main thread, so the second performSelector won't be called, since the first call never returns.

You should really, really get rid of performSelector and switch to GCD. I wouldn't want to see performSelector and sleep calls in any code written today.

Comment: I moved the @autoreleasepool inside the loop and the memory keeps on going. Could it be that some elements inside the captureImage methods stay in the memory for some reason ?
I will look into the GCD, thanks. 
I know that my first performSelector runs in the main thread, and the second one in background, but how can it be that when I replace the captureImage call by a NSLog, the switchManualMode gets called ?
Should it be called either everytime or never (since I'm in an infinite loop even with the NSLog) ?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use recursion for this type of things:

```
-(void)buttonTappedMethod
{
    [self recusionMethod];
}

-(void)recursionMethod
{
    if(self.isAutoMode)
    {
        // ------------------------------------------------
        // Do something
        // 
        // change self.isAutoMode = YES 
        // on condition satisfied in this logic block
        // ------------------------------------------------

        // ------------------------------------------------
        // call this method again
        // ------------------------------------------------
        [self recursionMethod];
    }
}
```